# Foreign Key class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, this is my first time using foreign keys, and though I think they are working properly, I don't understand the class_name portion in the syntax. Is that the class_name that the table being referred to is in?

My code:

Game Model:

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'white_player_id', class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'black_player_id', class_name: 'User'
```

User Model:

```
has_many :games, foreign_key: 'white_player_id', class_name: 'Game'
has_many :games, foreign_key: 'black_player_id', class_name: 'Game'
```

I was looking at: http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/rails-models.html and noitced that in their example they have the class name of both belongs_to and has_many pointing to the Folder class..

```
belongs_to :parent, :foreign_key => 'parent_id' class_name: 'Folder'
has_many :folders, :foreign_key => 'parent_id', class_name: 'Folder'
```

So, that leads me to believe that the class name is supposed to point to the class that contains the foreign_key?? A little insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `class_name` refers to the Type that the relationship refers to.  Or as you put it, the table being referred to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define multiple assocations with the same name your just overwriting the same assocation.

```
belongs_to :white_player, foreign_key: 'white_player_id', class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :black_player, foreign_key: 'black_player_id', class_name: 'User'
```

`class_name` is the class of the related object.

`foreign_key` refers to the table of the model class where you are defining the relationship when defining a `belongs_to` relationsship.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :white_player, foreign_key: 'white_player_id', class_name: 'User'
  # foreign_key is game.white_player_id
end
```

So when we do `game.white_player` Active Record looks for:

```
User.find(game.white_player_id)
```

### added:

In your second example `foreign_key` in `has_many` refers to the related table.

```
belongs_to :parent, :foreign_key => 'parent_id' class_name: 'Folder'
has_many :folders, :foreign_key => 'parent_id', class_name: 'Folder'
```

And you would not need to specify the foreign key and class name explicitly:

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ActiveRecord will infer that the class name is Folder
  has_many :folders, foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  # Rails will infer that the foreign_key is parent_id
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Folder'
end
```

As you can see ActiveRecord is one smart cookie and can infer class names and foreign keys.

Here is an easier to explain example of `has_many` and `foreign_keys`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :unread_messages, -> { where read: false }, 
           foreign_key: 'recipient_id', # refers to messages.recipient_id
           class_name: 'Message'
end
```

`user.unread_messages` will query the table message:

```
SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."recipient_id" # ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you mean, I guess I am lost where the :white_player and :black_player would be 'stored'?

Nevermind, it clicked. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: The second example is a bit complex and confusing since its a self joining table. You can read more about them here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: There's no need to specify foreign key explicitly if it can be derived from association name. (such as `belongs_to :parent, foreign_key: 'parent_id'`). Convention over configuration.

Answer (score 2):

class_name is for the class which is used in method you use, if ActiveRecord can not decide which class it is. In your example you dont need class_name because your method is `user` and class that will connect to is `User`, ActiveRecord can figure that out on its own.

You have another problem. You have two relations with same name `user` and `user`, that is not posible.
You could made it like this though:

Game Model:

```
belongs_to :white_player, foreign_key: 'white_player_id', class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :black_player, foreign_key: 'black_player_id', class_name: 'User'
```

UserModel:

```
has_many :white_games, class_name: 'Game'
has_many :black_games, class_name: 'Game'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, @papirtiger explained it in a little more detail or you would have gotten the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create it with a new model, the simpliest way to do it :

Migration - 1/2 : **console**

rails g model Game white_player:references black_player:references

Migration - 2/2 : **db/migrate/create_games.rb**

In the migration file, delete the **"foreign_key: true"** entry, that would look like :

```
t.references :white_player, foreign_key: true
t.references :black_player, foreign_key: true
```

**Run : rails db:migrate**

## Model files :

Game Model :

```
belongs_to :white_player, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :black_player, class_name: 'User'
```

User Model :

```
has_many :white_player_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'white_player_id'
has_many :black_player_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'white_player_id'
```

Hope that helps.